# Jquery: Sort table by input value automatically after changing value

Tags: jquery, user-input, tablesorter

How do I sort a table based on the values in INPUTs in specific column. I want it to happen as soon as I change the value of any of the inputs in the spcified column. I've tried with the tablesort plugin but just cant make it to work.

```
<table id="myDummyTable" class="tablesorter"><thead>
<tr>
    <th>...</th>
    <th id="orderthis">something</th>
    <th id="orderthis">order by value automatically</th>
    <th id="orderthis2">...</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>td1-1</td><td><input type="text" class="stockprodvariantorder" value="abc"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="order1" class="order" value="10"/></td>
    <td>td1-3</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>td2-1</td><td><input type="text" class="stockprodvariantorder" value="def"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="order2" class="order" value="20"/></td>
    <td>td4-3</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>td6-1</td><td><input type="text" class="stockprodvariantorder" value="ghi"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="order3" class="order" value="30"/></td>
    <td>td3-3</td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td>td4-1</td><td><input type="text" class="someOther" value="jkl"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="order4" class="order" value="40"/></td>
    <td>td4-3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: anything you have tired on it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you really want your application to behave this way? You essentially force the user to not make typos, because if she does the table row might be somewhere. If your table is larger than the viewport, it will also scroll around the window if she continues typing. At least consider only re-sorting when focus changes (i.e. on blur).

To answer your question: You need to write a custom text extractor function, like the one below:

```
var myTextExtraction = function(node) {
  // return value of input field (must be a direct child of <td>)
  return node.childNodes[0].value; 
} 

$(document).ready(function() {
  // init table sorter
  $("#myDummyTable").tableSorter({textExtraction: myTextExtraction});

  // listen to keyup events on each input and resort each time
  $("#myDummyTable input").keyup(function() {
    // sort by 2nd column
    $("#myDummyTable").trigger("sorton", [[1,0]]); 
  });
});
```

I haven’t tested above code, report back if you have problems. But like Nitesh Verma hinted, include more details on what doesn’t work.

Documentation links:

- http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html
- http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html